# What is the best way to use Rspec to test parsing from a file?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, file, rspec

Right now I am doing my testing by creating a controller for passing in the name of the file, parsing the file in the model and adding the necessary information added as a row in my database, which is then displayed on a page.  I am then comparing the fields on the page to what the fields should be.

But this seems messy since the controller and display page were created only for the purposes of these tests.  Is there a way to just feed the file name into a method in my model, and then run the usual tests against the database info itself?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to answer this if we had a code sample (of the controller and model) to see why this shouldn't be handled in the standard rspec idiom.

Without knowing about your controller or model, I can at least say this: Yes, you can do that. The basic procedure to follow is to create your test file (if you need to), feed the name/path in to the test using a standard variable (yes, most likely hard coded, though it depends on how extensive you're planning to be), then test it against your database in whatever your standard way to do such things is.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that the way I described it above is the standard idiom or is not?  And when you are saying I can do that, are you saying the way I'm doing it or calling the specific function with a file name and bypassing the controller?  The only reason I'm asking is that it seems messy to involved a controller and view when they serve no purpose other than the test.

Comment: The way that you described it above feels very much like the standard idiom. Whether you decide to test the controller or the models only is more of a difference in the type of test you're running. A model test is more of a standard Test::Unit. For testing controllers, you're more talking about a functional test. Getting a more holistic "stack view" of your application, which generally falls under rspec more than Test::Unit. Make sense? Here is a rails guide entry that might help! http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#unit-testing-your-models

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a unit test of your model. Create a test input file, pass it to the model in your test, and then assert that the fields in the test file match what got inserted into the database.